# Break the flatMapIterable loop RXJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have one list and I am iteratating it through flatMapIterable. However, I want to break the iteration if some specific element comes in between the iteration. E.g.

```
 val list = Single.just(listOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6))
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable { it }
            .map {
                if(it == 3 ) TODO(" Break the iteration here.")
            }
```

In I want to iterate the list of 1..6 and I want to stop the itearation if 3 comes in between, how can I do that?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) operator

It would look like the following:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6))
            .takeUntil{ it != 3 }
```

If you want to ignore 3 then you can use [skipLast](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skiplast.html) operator:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6))
            .takeUntil{ it != 3 }
            .skipLast(1)
```